# How can i change de background-image of a div via detecting the path I am on?

Tags: angular, routes

I'm Working with Angular doing a Portfolio Web.

In my app.component.html I have this:

```
<div class="fondo-dinamico">   
    <app-nav></app-nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

"fondo-dinamico" is the class of the div that contains my navbar and my sections (That change thanks to the router-outlet).

What I want to do is:

Example:

When router-outlet == home
--> background-image 1

When router-outlet == about
--> background-image 2

I have not tried anything because I don't know if what I want could in fact be done. I researched, but I found nothing.

I have 2 months to complete this project. So I thought it would be smart to ask this question now and hopefully find a solution before then.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to listen to **activate** event of the RouterOutlet. [Docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#properties)

Something like this:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onRouterOutletActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

In TS file a corresponding handler, which will update a `backgroundImageUrl` member variable:

```
  public onRouterOutletActivate(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
    this.backgroundImageUrl = event.backgroundImageUrl;  // <-- set the background image
  }
```

This member variable is again used in HTML to set the background image:

```
<div
  class="fondo-dinamico"
  [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + backgroundImageUrl + ')' }"
>
```

Each component Home and About has this member variable:

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  backgroundImageUrl = 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/600';
```

and

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  backgroundImageUrl = 'https://picsum.photos/id/160/600';
```

Another option is to listen to Router events like:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('on init');

    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if (evt.url === '/home') {
          console.log('at home'); // <-- update background image here
        }
        if (evt.url === '/about') {
          console.log('at about'); // <-- update background image here
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jsuwgp?file=src/app/app.component.ts)